# Using boolean expression outside of a where/having clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following data:

```
store_id    store_name  phone   email   street  city    state   zip_code
1   Santa Cruz Bikes    (831) 476-4321  santacruz@bikes.shop    3700 Portola Drive  Santa Cruz  CA  95060
2   Baldwin Bikes   (516) 379-8888  baldwin@bikes.shop  4200 Chestnut Lane  Baldwin NY  11432
3   Rowlett Bikes   (972) 530-5555  rowlett@bikes.shop  8000 Fairway Avenue Rowlett TX  75088
```

If I write a query such as:

```
select * from sales.stores where email='rowlett@bikes.shop'
-- store_id store_name  phone   email   street  city    state   zip_code
-- 3    Rowlett Bikes   (972) 530-5555  rowlett@bikes.shop  8000 Fairway Avenue Rowlett TX  75088
```

I get the expected result with one row. However, if I use the exact same expression in the select list, I get what seems like gibberish:

```
SELECT email='rowlett@bikes.shop' from sales.stores where email='rowlett@bikes.shop'
-- email
-- rowlett@bikes.shop
```

Why does SQL Server return the result `rowlett@bikes.shop` for the expression `email=rowlett@bikes.shop` ? I understand it doesn't have the boolean type, but I'd think it would be converted to something like `1`. Why does that occur?

Comment: because `column_alias= expression` is an alternative way of writing `expression as column_alias` - per the grammar https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: @MartinSmith thanks that is just what I was looking for, the fourth alternation in the syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Martin Smith pointed out in the comments, whether you use:

```
SELECT email = 'rowlett@bikes.shop' ...
```

or

```
SELECT 'rowlett@bikes.shop' AS email ...
```

you'll get the same query result - that is, you'll get a column named 'email' in your query resultset, with 'rowlett@bikes.shop' as the value for each row.

```
|email               |column2|column3|
 -------------------- ------- -------
|'rowlett@bikes.shop'|value1 |another value1|
|'rowlett@bikes.shop'|value2 |another value2|
etc.
```

To go one step further beyond your question (making the assumption that you actually do want to have a true/false value returned in your query results), then you can use a CASE expression to achieve that - eg.

```
SELECT
CONVERT(bit,
CASE 
  WHEN email = 'rowlett@bikes.shop' 
  THEN 1 
  ELSE 0 
END
)
FROM sales.stores;
```

And expanding that to see some potential results:

```
SELECT
email,
CONVERT(bit,
CASE 
  WHEN email = 'rowlett@bikes.shop' 
  THEN 1 
  ELSE 0 
END
) AS EmailCheck
FROM sales.stores;
```

you'd see something like:

```
|email                |EmailCheck |
|'rowlett@bikes.shop' |1 |
|'someone@xyz.com'    |0 |
|'someoneelse@xyz.com'|0 |
```